# DecimalFormat behaves different if decimal ends with 5 digit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, decimalformat

**DecimalFormat** is behaving differently on Android [Kotlin] vs. Kotlin scratch file in my Android Studio, if decimal digits end at 5.

For example; if I try to format **10.495** with **2** decimal places, Android shows **10.50** while Kotlin scratch file returns **10.49**.

Please note that my Mac OSX has java 17 installed, so Kotlin file is running on Java 17. While `build.gradle` has been configured to use jvm 11. I tried to use Jvm 17 in build.gradle, but still the result was same.

##### Code:

```
fun formatNumber(num: Double): String {
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")
    df.roundingMode = HALF_EVEN
    return df.format(num)
}
```

**Formatted Result on Android**

| Original Value | Rounded off |
| --- | --- |
| 23.805 | 23.80 |
| 15.985 | 15.98 |
| 10.495 | 10.50 <-- |
| 49.505 | 49.50 <-- |

**Formatted Result on Kotlin Scratch File**

| Original Value | Rounded off |
| --- | --- |
| 23.805 | 23.80 |
| 15.985 | 15.98 |
| 10.495 | 10.49 <-- |
| 49.505 | 49.51 <-- |

Please note the difference in last two numbers. I want to understand why both have different results. I have tried different rounding modes, but none helps. Even iOS and web has results same as Kotlin scratch file. I came across [this](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7131459) bug in JDK, but it has been marked resolved. Even using BigDecimal doesn't help. How can I make sure it rounds off correctly if last digit is 5 using existing language libs? Any direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Android does not use open JDK.  So any bugs opened in it or closed in it are immaterial.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan thanks for reply. I am curious to know how android uses java libraries? We include jvm version and source + target compatibility in build.gradle. Therefore project's compilation does depend upon java version installed on machine. Android by default includes which java version? If you can tell or point towards some source to read. Thank you.

Comment: THe JDK is not the only implementation of Java.  There's several of them.  Android doesn't use the open JDK version.  It uses the ART version.  Before that it used Dalvik.  It has never used OpenJDK. https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THat's the rounding mode you specified.  HALF_EVEN means an exact .5 rounds to the even number.  Specify the rounding mode you prefer if you don't want that.  HALF_UP may be what you want.

Comment: Your comment and answer together makes some sense. I need to inform my team that this is how Android functions! Thank you.